# django : How can i check if an object is exist in a many-to-many relation?

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model named Post that has some fields like this :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True , unique=True , null=True , blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User , blank=True , help_text="amount of likes")
    likes_count = models.IntegerField(default=0 , help_text="amount of likes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and I have a view that needs to check if the user is in "likes" relation and do some stuff . But I don't know what to do ! this is my view:

```
def Like_view(request , slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=slug)
    if not request.user in post.likes:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        post.likes_count += 1
        post.save()
    else:
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        post.likes_count -= 1
        post.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to save count of likes.

in your case:

```
likes_count = post.likes.count()
# or 
likes_count = post.likes.aggregate(likes_count=Count('*')).get('likes_count')
```

## more here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions

For your view I prefer to delete like, if returns nothing - it means you don't have a like and you can create it:

```
def Like_view(request , slug):
    if not Post.likes.through.objects.filter(post__slug=slug, user = post.user).delete():
        get_object_or_404(Post , slug=slug).likes.add(request.user)
```

And my opinion, the sheme can be better, with boolean checkbox in through model. In this case you can do only one DB call:

```
Post.likes.through.objects.filter(post__slug=slug, user = post.user).update(is_like=Q(is_like=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for backward relation:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = ...
    slug = ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, blank=True, help_text="amount of likes", related_name="likes"
    )
    likes_count = ...
```

views.py

```
def like_view(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    user_likes = request.user.likes.all()
    liked = True if post in user_likes else False

    if request.method == "POST":
        if liked:
            request.user.likes.remove(post)
            post.likes_count -= 1
            post.save()
        else:
            request.user.likes.add(post)
            post.likes_count += 1
            post.save()
        return redirect(reverse("like-view", kwargs={"slug": post.slug}))

    context = {"post": post, "liked": liked}

    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<slug:slug>', like_view, name='like-view')
]
```

post_detail.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'like-view' post.slug %}" method="post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if liked %}
            <button type="submit">Unlike</button>
            {% else %}
            <button type="submit">Like</button>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the view like this :

```
def Like_view(request , slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=slug)
    if not post.likes.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        post.likes_count += 1
        post.save()
    else:
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        post.likes_count -= 1
        post.save()
```

Comment: how i tell abowe, you can check through model, not the m2m model, it is faster. And in your example you did 4 DB calls instead of 1 or 2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).